# Create a table in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to create a column with values specified in SQL statement. Result should look like this:

```
-- +---------+
-- | Title   |
-- +---------+
-- | Title 1 |
-- | Title 2 | 
-- | Title 3 |
-- | Title 4 |
-- +---------+
```

I know the way with using syntax SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Title 1' as Title),(SELECT 'Title 2' as Title),... 
Is there any shorter way how to do that? I have hundreds of the values there and I need specify them in SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT SPLIT(Titles) AS Title 
FROM (SELECT 'Title 1,Title 2,Title 3,Title 4' AS Titles)
```

You can use [`FLATTEN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#flatten) operator to flatten result of SPLIT
See example below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT * 
FROM FLATTEN(( 
    SELECT SPLIT(Titles) AS Title 
    FROM (SELECT 'xy,zx' AS Titles)
  ), Title) AS A 
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT Name, Title 
  FROM table.name
) AS Names
ON A.Title=Names.Title
```

Comment: Still, You should migrate to BigQuery Standard SQL - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql

Comment: Just noticed that I can't merge the result with other table because of repeated field. Any idea?

Comment: SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      SPLIT(Titles) AS Title
    FROM (
      SELECT
        'xy,zx' AS Titles)) AS A
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      Name,
      Title
    FROM
table.name AS Names
  ON
    A.Title=Names.Title)

Comment: @JohnSnow - see update/addition in my answer. If you have more questions - please post new one with all related details :o)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to get you started using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Title
FROM UNNEST([
  'Title 1',
  'Title 2',
  'Title 3'
]) AS Title;
```

You can add as many titles to the list as you want. If you are using the BigQuery API, you can [pass an array type query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#using_arrays_in_parameterized_queries) to avoid having to include the list in the query text itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I can use just Legacy SQL.

Comment: Why can't you use standard SQL?