# BigQuery SPLIT manual creation of table

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery

In reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134145/create-a-table-in-big-query) I would like to create multiple columns manually.

```
SELECT SPLIT(Titles) AS Title 
FROM (SELECT 'Title 1,Title 2,Title 3,Title 4' AS Titles)
```

I have tried simply adding new column like this:

```
SELECT SPLIT(Titles) AS Title, SPLIT(Names) AS Name,FROM (SELECT 'Title 1,Title 2,Title 3,Title 4' AS Titles, 'Name 1,Name 2,Name 3,Name 4' AS NAMES)
```

However BQ shows me following error:

```
Error: Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time. Found Title and Name
```

I think it could be related how BQ flatten the results and I found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583878/flattening-google-analytics-data-with-repeated-fields-not-working-anymore). Unfortunately I am not able to transform my code. I can use just Legacy SQL.

EDIT: 
Expected table should look like this:

```
-- +---------+--------+
-- | Title   | Name   |
-- +---------+--------+
-- | Title 1 | Name 1 |
-- | Title 2 | Name 2 | 
-- | Title 3 | Name 3 |
-- | Title 4 | Name 4 |
-- +---------+--------+
```

Comment: can you provide what exactly result you expect as it can vary

Comment: I edited the post. Basically it should add the column with the same number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'Title 1,Title 2,Title 3,Title 4' AS Titles, 'Name 1,Name 2,Name 3,Name 4' AS Names
)
SELECT 
  Title, 
  Name
FROM data, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(Titles)) AS Title WITH OFFSET AS pos1, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(Names)) AS Name WITH OFFSET AS pos2
WHERE pos1 = pos2  
ORDER BY Title
```

Same idea in BigQuery Legacy SQL looks a little  more bushy

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  Title, Name
FROM FLATTEN((
  SELECT Title,  POSITION(Title) AS pos1
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(Titles) AS Title
    FROM (SELECT 'Title 1,Title 2,Title 3,Title 4' AS Titles, 'Name 1,Name 2,Name 3,Name 4' AS Names)
  )
), pos1) AS titles
JOIN FLATTEN((
  SELECT Name, POSITION(Name) AS pos2
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(Names) AS Name
    FROM (SELECT 'Title 1,Title 2,Title 3,Title 4' AS Titles, 'Name 1,Name 2,Name 3,Name 4' AS Names)
  )
), pos2) AS names
ON pos1 = pos2
```

Comment: @johnsnow - did you have chance to try?